# Can this push pull oscillator improved for experimental realization?

Tags: power-supply, analog, power-electronics, oscillator, wireless

I am using the following push pull oscillator circuit  is extracted from this [Application Note](https://www.we-online.com/web/en/index.php/download/media/07_electronic_components/download_center_1/application_notes_berichte/anp032_wireless_power_transfer_hohe_leistungen_industriellen_umfeld/ANP032g_EN.pdf) for implementation of a wireless charging system. In simulations, it's efficiency is above above 85% when coupling is 0.1. (I used parasitic resistances of L1 and L2 as 15mOhm which is realistic value for coils made using litz wires. The efficiency of this is highly determined by the coil quality factor - I want to exclude this in answers)

[image]

MY questions are:

1. How can I improve this oscillator circuit (not the Wireless Power System parameters )  in terms of efficiency, reliability or any other practical issues? - is there any better componet selection or better drive circuit?
2. Can we use this topology for high frequencies, for example, at 1 MHz? If possible, how can we improve it to use at high frequencies? If not, do we have any other oscillator topology  suitable for high frequency operation?

I also want to stick into a self oscillating circuit- I understand that pulse control topologies  like h-bridge conver or class E can be high efficient but for this application, I want to exclude them.

Comment: Coil gap must < diameter and impedance matching for MPT means 50% loss but lower source/load ratio  means higher efficiency

Comment: Thanks, Here, I am concerned about practical aspects of the oscillator circuit - not the parameters of WPT. For instance, if the distance is fixed and the load is optimised for maximum efficiency.

Comment: Then don’t use 10 Ohms in series with \$\omega L\$. Use a proper Half Bridge with adequate deadtime. It is much better to raise impedance of both coils using setup and step down to be much higher than mutual impedance

Comment: 10Ohms is in series with gate - resonance current doesn’t flow through it though. Well, I want to stick to a self oscillating circuit.

Comment: Ah yes resonant frequency may change with everything unknown but it ought to be low Q when power is transferred .  You can make a half or full bridge oscillate with secondary windings with positive feedback like a Boost converter but DC to AC with high boost E field and low H field e.g higher Z than Mutual impedance to gain efficiency then step down with a synchronous ZVS AC to DC converter.  It’s been done before

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist, do you have a reference link to any such design?

Comment: The speed at which M3 and M4 turn on affects efficiency - the slower the speed the more heat lost. Also Lc1 and Lc2 resistance/losses have a significant effect.

Comment: @Andyaka, Do you suggest using any other better MOSFET?