# What characteristics should I look for when choosing a Zener Diode as a voltage limiter?

Tags: mosfet, oscillator, components, component-selection

I am trying to use voltage limiting zener diode for a MOSFET gate in the following oscillator circuit . ([related to this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383783/can-this-push-pull-oscillator-improved-for-experimental-realization)) [image] 
What characteristics should I look for when choosing a Zener Diode for gate voltage limiting and how it relates to the operation of this circuit? E.g. series resistance, parasitic capacitance etc.

Comment: Why not choose devices with suitable Avalanche + zener diodes? What output power?

Comment: I see how you're trying to limit the Vgs of M3 and M4 using zeners. However, I expect to see a current limiting resistor, similar to how in a shunt regulator there's a resistor to drop the excess voltage. In the circuit as is you rely on M1 and M2 to drop that excess voltage. In the case where M1 or M2 is fully on the current through the zener diodes might exceed what they can handle. I would add small (100 ohm) resistors between points S1 and the gate, same for S2 of course.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist, Thanks, Can you suggest such a a model? I could not find any zener which explicitly says that it is avalanche - [this link](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~jones/es154/lectures/lecture_2/breakdown/breakdown.html) was useful to see the difference.

Comment: Can't you define more specs on Voltage range , max Power transfer, desired efficiency?  Have you simulated Fig 16 in https://www.we-online.com/web/en/index.php/download/media/07_electronic_components/download_center_1/application_notes_berichte/anp032_wireless_power_transfer_hohe_leistungen_industriellen_umfeld/ANP032g_EN.pdf  50W . do this 1st

Comment: My target specs: power ~10W, output voltage ~20V, efficiency 80% at 0.1 coupling (Highly dependent on my coils and coupling - Therefore, I'd like to improve my Oscillator. As requested suggestions [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383783/can-this-push-pull-oscillator-improved-for-experimental-realization) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/386503/can-i-modify-this-oscillator-to-ensure-zvs).  I have not tried simulating Fig 16, will simulate it and see the results.