# Wireless power transfer circuit to attain ~5W of power on the receiving end

Tags: mosfet, inductor, 555, wireless-charging

I am designing a WPT system to run a ws1812 based pixel chain. The ws2812 pixel chain runs on 5v and consumes 500-800ma of power, means 2.5w-4w. The system I made is not able to transfer adequate power to the receiving end load.
Here are my circuits:
[image]

The transmitter is driven with a 12v 5a smps power supply. Initially the current consumption of the transmitter circuit was 0.3A-0.4A, then I tuned the oscillator to oscillate at the resonant frequency of the LC tank, hence forming the LC tuned circuit to transfer max amount of power. As resonance the current consumption is at minimum (~20ma). So far so good.
For the transmitter I actually made a bridge rectifier using 4 BA159, and removed the regulator part at all for initial testing however the 2.2k resistance stays on the circuit.
Observation: 
1. No Load scenario - When no load is connected, means the load is 2.2k alone, the current on the transmitter is ~600ma, and the capacitor (.1u, 250v) is pretty hot, and the resistance is quite hot as well. The voltage at this state is ~30v.

2. A cpu fan as load: I added a 12v cpu fan as the load. Current on the transmitter is ~250ma, current on the receiver is ~80-100ma, voltage across load reduces to 14v. From this I can calculate that the power transferred is 14v*100ma=1.4w. This is the max power I could draw on the receiver.
3. I tried to add a ws2812 led series of 50 led, which is my goal. I used a lm2596 based dc-dc buck regulator to reduce the voltage to ~5v, as we know pixel runs on 5v. the chain I use has a controller also. As soon as I connect the chain with the output of buck regulator, the voltage drops to ~2.2v, and never goes beyond this. The input of the regulator, that is the output of the receiver circuit voltage drops to ~3.5v from 29v (when open). At this state only red leds are glowing and no animations are running due to low voltage. As this state I measured the current through the led chain and found it to be 250ma. The power hence becomes 2.2v*250ma=550mw.
   Questions
4. My question is why the phenomenon with led is happening? If the max power transfer amount is 1400mw, then the voltage should not have reduced such low, it should be at least able to provide 5v as 5v*250ma = 1250mw.
5. What should I do to get 5v 1a on the output.

Circuit analysis:
At resonance the the resistance Ra and Rb are 1k and 2.8k respectively. SO total resistance across 6 and 7 is ~2.9k. According to astable multivibrator formula the frequency of oscillation is =1.44/((Ra+2*Rb)*C) that gives 211.764khz, this is also the resonance frequency of the LC tank. I am not precisely able to measure the inductance of the coil due to lack of suitable apparatus, but from calculation I get the coil inductance should be 120uh from (L=1/(4*pi^2*f^2*c)). I calculated the inductance using the calculator on https://m0ukd.com/calculators/air-cored-inductor-calculator/. (coil diameter D=65mm, L=5mm, and N=25) gives me 88uh, which is close but not matching.

Transmitter:
[image]
Overlapping Transmitter & Receiver
[image]

Comment: 0.1 uF getting hot needs looking at. Why? Also, 30 V (DC steady?) into 2k2 ~= 0.5 Watt. What is resistor wattage. Resonant unloaded voltage CAN be HIGH. | Air cores? | Coil separation? Coil alignment?

Comment: Resonance is crucial. An oscillator using the primary tank for oscillation is about as easy as what you have and then MUST be in resonance. Low unloaded Iosc suggests ~= resonance. An oscilloscope shows this VERY clearly. An AC voltmeter MAY but an eg single diode peak rectifier and cap and high R bleed resistor to drain cap allows easy DC peak V measurement. | Secondary resonance is crucial. Again - scope excellent - but adding caps in small steps sequentially to a slightly under L inductance to tune through resonance will make resonance point VERY clear. eg say multiple 0.01 or 0.0047 uF .

Comment: Can it be certainly said if both tanks are at resonant frequency the required power would be delivered on secondary?

Comment: As you have said both tanks have to be resonant, for primary I am making sure that it is resonant by tuning the astable mv frequency using the pot as I already explained. How to tune the secondary

Comment: I am also curious about the power dissipated in 2k2 resistor. Should I get rid of this one. In general when we use transformer we use bridge rectifier and and capacitor, so its like a no load condition where no power is dissipated on secondary. I think the concept should be similar here. But when I remove the 2.2k load, and bring the coils together the current dissipated at primary is ~0.6A, and the 0.1uf cap gets extreme hot immediately. Does this indicate significant lack of resonance on receiver?

Comment: If you don't address all the questions asked and/or comment on what you have done about things suggested and instead ask more questions we are unlikely to solve things rapidly. || Do you have an oscilloscop? Have you measured the peak voltages? (method suggested above) What is the 2k2 wattage rating? Why is the 0.1 uF getting hot?/does another one get hot? -> implications ara that Vresonance is >> cap rating ... | Question re poswer is too ill defined so far - but many Watts should be easy enough.  | You spot secondary resonance by doing what I said. It will be obious. Measure Vtank somehow.

Comment: When you are not capable of tuning the resonance, the best way would be to go with identical Tx and Rx coils and a self-oscillating circuit to drive the Tx. The self-oscillating circuit will automatically track the resonance. for example, see this circuit  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383783/can-this-push-pull-oscillator-improved-for-experimental-realization

Comment: Hello Russell, Pardon me for re-questioning. I added some images. I was actually testing with identical receiver and transmitter. So please ignore the previous scenario. Here are the rest of the answers - 2k2 .25w, The cap .1uf was of 100v, so not exceeding cap rating, The cap i am presently using are of 400v rating and they are not getting hot.

Comment: Latest readings - with 2k2 attached - AC volt across tank - 10v, dc output - 45v, current drawn at transmitter - 0.19A, without 2k2, open circuit dc output 57v, AC volt >100v

Comment: the mosfet is directly driven via 555 out, should i add a mosfet driver in-between? please note the frequency is ~200khz, so at this frequency can 555 deliver enough current to drive the mosfet properly?